# How can I enable displaying website into the iframe?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iframe, drupal, web-deployment

I encountered a problem with displaying my website into the frame to show click map. An error is: "Refused to display 'https://balticland.ru/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'." But I don't have any prohibitions for that. [Here is my .htaccess file.](http://pastebin.com/ngyxUT44)

I am using Drupal.

Can you advise me something?

Answer (score 1):

X-Frame_Options is header option and it should be sent with header function before any output begins. Something like:

```
<?php header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); ?>
```

Drupal has special function for setting http headers:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7.x

So it should be something like:

```
drupal_add_http_header('X-Frame-Options', 'GOFORIT');
```

Check out comments bellow function description.

**Update:**

Check out this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

It can be that you must specify external origin, like it states:

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! I have added this function to the end of bootstrap.inc. But now it still shows an error: "Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://balticland.ru/': 'GOFORIT' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored."

And this (http://mainspy.ru/otvet_servera) test still shows "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header"